# C program to convert Octal to Hexadecimal number system

Tags: c

i have written the code below to covert octal to hexadecimal number:

```
int main()
{
int octal[100]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
int binary[100]={0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000,1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111};
int Hinary[100]={0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000,1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111};
long long tempoctal,last1,binar,hocatl,place=1;
long long i,tempbinary,last2,index;
char hexadecimal[100];
index=0;
binar=0;

printf("enter an octal number:  ");
scanf("%lld",&hocatl);

tempoctal=hocatl;

while(tempoctal != 0){

    last1=tempoctal%10;

    binar=(binary[last1] * place) + binar;


    place *= 1000;

    tempoctal /=10;

}

tempbinary=binar;
printf("this is the number: %lld",tempbinary);

while(tempbinary != 0){

    last2=tempbinary%10000;
      for(i=0 ; i<16 ; i++){

       if(Hinary[i] == last2){
       if(i<10){  hexadecimal[index]= i + '0';  }
       else{  hexadecimal[index]= (i-10) + 'A' ;  }
       }

      }
    index++;
    tempbinary /=10000;


}
hexadecimal[index]= '\O';
strrev(hexadecimal);
printf("\nthis is the hex: %s",hexadecimal);
```

the problem is that the program work but in every hex output there is a zero before the hex number and i don't know why.

[image: Output]

Comment: Because you're putting one in explicitly? `hexadecimal[index]= '\O';` Did you mean `\0`, which terminates a string, i.e. a zero not O?

Comment: `\O` is not a valid escape sequence so this will not even compile. Please post the real code. Or otherwise if your compiler let this through, it is configured in very strange ways and you need to get to the bottom of that.

Comment: sir RUP it is a ZERO not O.

Comment: No it's not a zero. In your screenshot there's a zero immediately underneath it, "Program returned 0", and it's different.

Comment: yeah, you right but i say that i had put ZERO in code block ,the out put is O.And i don't know why

Comment: It's the line just before `strrev`. I can copy and paste it from your question into a hex editor, and it's definitely an 'O' not a '0'. Look at your compile warnings: you'll see "warning C4129: 'O': unrecognized character escape sequence" - double-click on that and that's the line you need to fix.

Comment: @Lundin GCC and MSVC both raise a warning for this (and by default - without any extra warning flags), but it does still compile.

Comment: If you are a beginner, always compile with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`. And `-Werror` doesn't hurt either. Don't ignore warnings!

Comment: in code block they are the same , just when i had past the code in stackoverflow the zero had change otherwise they have te same shape.

Comment: thank all of you the probleme resolved, i just forgot the warnings

Comment: an 'octal' number can only have 0...7 in each digit.  Never `8,9,`

Comment: For the compiler to recognize a number as being 'octal', it must start with 0

Answer (score 1):

I think it appears because of

```
if(i<10){  hexadecimal[index]= i + '0';  }
```

To fix your zero problem, you can use this before printing:

```
if (hexadecimal[0] == '0')
{
    hexadecimal++;
}
```

Also, as Rup says, in the comments, you use '\O', from Oliver, not '\0', here:

```
hexadecimal[index]= '\O';
```

Comment: No,it is a zero not O, but it just appear like that.